# Angular CLI does not generate component at the right path

Tags: angular, angular-cli, auto-generate

First of all, I should admit I'm very new to the [`angular-cli`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

As the title says, I'm trying to generate components/services/etc.. using the CLI providing a path for the generated files but it does not place it there.

The problem must be in the fact I changed the generated `app` directory to some other name, it keeps generating it there..

What I've done exactly is:

- `ng new`
- renaming of the generated `app` to `not-app`
- `ng -g component not-app/component/some-component-dir/some-component`

instead of generating it exactly where i specified, it for some reason creates an `app` directory AGAIN and then providing the file in the path I specified under it.

Reading their docs I figured I'm doing it the right way but I guess something's wrong

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

try changing the prefix in the `angular-cli.json` from "`app`" to "`not-app`" - then restart terminal and should work ok

Comment: unfortunately that did not work, any other suggestion?

Comment: try running the command from within the directory you're interested in

Comment: Already have tried that, it just generates the `app` dir under the base `src` with less nested directories..